# return dynamic generated file without creating tmp version?

Tags: python, django, imagemagick

On my django server, I create an image file with imagemagick via the command line.

```
cmd = local_file + " -crop 50%x50%+10+10 " + temp_final_file

out, err = subprocess.Popen( cmd.split(), 
                  stdin = subprocess.PIPE,
                  stdout = subprocess.PIPE,
                  stderr = subprocess.PIPE ).communicate()
```

I then return the file back to the client:

```
    mt = mimetypes.guess_type( temp_final_file )[0]
    with open( temp_final_file, "rb" ) as f:
       response = HttpResponse( f.read(), mimetype=mt )
    return response
```

I am wondering if I can avoid writing a local file and instead just return the bytes directly?

Comment: The python module StringIO http://docs.python.org/2/library/stringio.html might work for you here.

Comment: note: the crop command is just an example.  running more complex commands through imagemagick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ImageMagick can write to its stdout, so you don't actually need the temporary file. Try this:

```
cmd = ['convert', local_file, '-crop', '50%x50%+10+10', '-']
new_image = subprocess.check_output( cmd )
response = HttpResponse( new_image, mimetype=mt )
```

Note: you still have to figure out the mime type. Without a file, that might be more difficult.

Comment: The '-' at the end is some imagemagick-fu I am not familiar with.  Interesting, thanks.

Comment: You can also say `'JPG:-'` or `'GIF:-'` to force a specific image format.

Comment: As I am on python 2.6 and haven't check_output, I've just adjusted my code in my OP to return the standard out and all  works.  much thanks!

Answer (score 0):

f.read() is just a python2 string of bytes. You can pass anything there.

You would have to use some interface than allows you to retrieve directly bytes, rather than write to a file. For example, an imagemagick wrapper, like this:

https://www.assembla.com/wiki/show/pythonmagickwand